# Connect to Wi-Fi C++

Tags: c++, windows, wifi

I searched everywhere... I did! I just couldn't find any example on **how to** connect to a Wi-Fi on C++.

I found and tried the examples of [WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706749%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WlanQueryInterface()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706765%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on MSDN. I also found an [example](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#WifiExample/WifiExample.cs) of what I'm searching for on C#. Could any one tell me one for **C++**?

Edit: I know nothing about the internet part of C++ (servers, Wifi APIs even not much of Win32 APIs), just the core of the language, I just want to make a **simple** program that finds an open connection and **automatically** connects to it and plays a sound if the connection was successful. If you can provide me with some **info** and **links** I'll do a research and post any solution I can find.

Comment: As far as you're concerned, you just connect to a server (or create a server to connect to). How the packets are transported is none of your concern. The OS takes care of that for you anyway.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706613(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RenanGemignani I tried the function and looked up the structs it uses and get an ERROR_SUCCESS but it doesn't connect. If I change the ucSSID to a non-existing one it returns success again.. It works for disconnection but not vice versa.

Comment: Shouldn't _Windows_ connect to the Wifi?  Not some random program?

Comment: What was wrong with WlanGetAvailableNetworkList?  Why didn't it work for you?  What problems did you encounter?  Can you show us an SSCCE so that we may help you?

Answer (score 4):

Given code is not advance type i.e. not that good but it does the work. I have use codeblock in windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ofstream xmlFile;
ifstream xmlFile1;

string name="",pass="";
string ntyp="Wi-Fi",netType,fileTest=">test.txt",check,ntype,fil,xfileName,fileName="myWlan.xml";
char c='"',cho='2',cho1='1',c1;
netType=c+ntyp+c+fileTest;
xfileName=c+fileName+c;
int succ=0;

 do
 {
      system("netsh wlan show networks");
      cout<<"   >--------------------         TO REFRESS PRESS :1       \n\n   >--------------------         TO CHOOSE NETWORK PRESS : 2              \n\n   >   ";
      cho=getch();
}while(cho!='2');

cout<<"\n    Enter the desired network name-------:       ";
cin>>name;
do
{
   cout<<"\n    Enter wifi Password------:        ";
    cin>>pass;
    xmlFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    //Writing a xml file .....................

    xmlFile<<"<?xml version="<<c<<"1.0"<<c<<"?>\n";
    xmlFile<<"<WLANProfile xmlns="<<c<<"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"<<c<<">\n";
    xmlFile<<"<name>";
    xmlFile<<name;
    xmlFile<<"</name>\n<SSIDConfig>\n<SSID>\n<hex>";
    for(int i=0;i<name.length();i++)
    xmlFile<<hex<<(int)name.at(i);
    xmlFile<<"</hex>\n<name>";
    xmlFile<<name;
    xmlFile<<"</name>\n</SSID>\n</SSIDConfig>\n<connectionType>ESS</connectionType>\n<connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>\n<MSM>\n<security>\n<authEncryption>";
    xmlFile<<"\n<authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>\n<encryption>AES</encryption>\n<useOneX>false</useOneX>\n</authEncryption>\n<sharedKey>";
    xmlFile<<"\n<keyType>passPhrase</keyType>\n<protected>false</protected>\n<keyMaterial>";
    xmlFile<<pass;
    xmlFile<<"</keyMaterial>\n</sharedKey>\n</security>\n</MSM>\n";
    xmlFile<<"<MacRandomization xmlns="<<c<<"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3"<<c<<">\n";
    xmlFile<<"<enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>\n</MacRandomization>\n</WLANProfile>";
    xmlFile.close();

    //addd the xml file to system profile.............
    system(("netsh wlan add profile filename="+xfileName).c_str());
    //to let system realize what changes have been made...............
    system("timeout /t 2");
    //to check if connected...........
    system(("netsh interface show interface name="+netType).c_str());

    xmlFile1.open("test.txt");
    while(!xmlFile1.eof())
    {
         xmlFile1>>c1;
         if(c1==':')
         {
              for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
              {
                   xmlFile1>>c1;
                   check=check+c1;
               }
         }
              if(check=="Connected")
              {
                  cout<<"...............................................You are connected!!.................................";
                  succ=1;break;
              }
              if(check!="Connected")check="";



    }
    xmlFile1.close();
    if(succ==1)break;
  }while(succ!=1);
return 0;
}
```

HOPE IT HELPS ....

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I guess you're looking for an enumeration function such as this one:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I guess what you mean is to check whether the WLan state is up. If you look closely the enumeration function returns a structure that includes isState which is one of those:

```
typedef enum _WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE { 
  wlan_interface_state_not_ready              = 0,
  wlan_interface_state_connected              = 1,
  wlan_interface_state_ad_hoc_network_formed  = 2,
  wlan_interface_state_disconnecting          = 3,
  wlan_interface_state_disconnected           = 4,
  wlan_interface_state_associating            = 5,
  wlan_interface_state_discovering            = 6,
  wlan_interface_state_authenticating         = 7
} WLAN_INTERFACE_STATE, *PWLAN_INTERFACE_STATE;
```

To actually "connect" you need to have a server listening on the other side... Although Renan gave you a good link too (see comment section of question) but that requires you to have an SSID. It depends whether your software would indeed know the Wifi SSIDs.

Comment: Well as long as I can get the SSIDs with `WlanGetAvailableNetworkList()` that wouldn't be a problem. If you're talking about the **hidden** ones - I won't mess with them.